# WSO2-APIM - InboundWebsocketSourceHandler Endpoint not found for port : 8099 tenant domain : null

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

i am using api manager 3.1.0 , i have configured web socket in api publisher  and configured  tenant=carbon.super
i am trying to access wss with domain name., i have updated host name with deployment.toml file,the problem is unable to access wss secure socket-.wss://test.com:8099/Notification/v1?access_token=xxx123 .i am getting error in connection, please guide me, how to resolve this

[2020-09-11 14:06:17,276] ERROR - **InboundWebsocketSourceHandler Endpoint not found for port : 8099 tenant domain : null**

[Error message screen clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4rJC.png)

Comment: Looks this is already addressed here https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/9256